# Response.Redirect causes localhost redirected you too many times error

Tags: c#, webforms

The problem is in my architecture.
On my master page I redirect user to "message" page, whose MasterPageFile is master page.
which leads to an error

> localhost redirected you too many times.

CustomMaster page

```
public partial class MasterPages_CustomMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsAuthenticated())
        {
            if (SomeLogic())
            {
                Response.Redirect("/message");
                return;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Message.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Custom.master" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="MessagePage" Codebehind="Default.aspx.cs" %>
```

I know that this is a code smell. I will keep this problem in mind when I start to refactor but I'm looking for a quick solution now. Doesn't matter how bad it smells

Comment: If master page is used in Message page then when you redirect to message page, it will execute the code of master page again causing another redirection casing same code executing again causing another redirection causing same code executing again and so on and on and on infinitely.

Comment: Why you want to redirect to message page? Why you have written this code in master page?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I need to check if User has X property enabled. It needs to be checked from master page. If X is not enabled, than it needs to go to message page. Which leads to this loop

Comment: I guess /message uses the same masterpage and SomeLogic() returns true always.

Comment: In your master page check to see if the page is the message page and if it is then don't execute IsAuthenticated and the other stuff.